# Why does type(list.append) return builtin_function_or_method instead of function *or* method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a very simple Python code.

```
items = [1, 2, 3]

sqr_list = []
for i in items:
    sqr_list.append(i**2)
sqr_list
```

each time I run this line

```
type(sqr_list.append)
```

I get

```
builtin_function_or_method
```

per the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html), `list.append(x)` is a method

Everything in Python is an object, and almost everything has attributes and methods.

in this particular case, sqr_list is an list object, and `sqr_list.append` is one of the methods of list objects.

Why does type don't be sure list.append is a method rather than a function?

Comment: `list` is one of the builtin, C implemented types. They differ in some points from Python classes. What you are observing is a symptom of that.

Comment: @KlausD. So, `sqr_list.append` is indeed a method, although type function cannot be sure, right?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the developers of the function thought that in this case the return value is sufficiently informative. There need not be a deep reason for what you observed.

Comment: "A method rather than a function" is rather ambiguous -- all methods *are* functions (though not all functions are also methods).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Would "A method instead of a function" be better?

Comment: @JohnColeman Does "what you observed" mean the output, 'builtin_function_or_method' in this case?

Comment: @czlsws Yes. You are essentially asking why someone designed a function which returns X rather than Y. The answer is seldom that the programmer really wished they could return Y but were for some deep reason unable to do so.

Comment: Design choice this is the answer